# Postgres - Find duplicate and update one of the row to zero

Tags: postgresql-9.2

Need your help, the below is my table structure in Postgres

```
Eid     Teamid  Working Days
1000067 166570  21
1000075 163138  21
1000086 163077  21
1000086 185102  21
```

The record 1000086 has two teams and I have to update one of the teams to 0 days. When this is displayed in the UI, the manager can update, but can you please help me with a better solution?

I am trying with different queries but finding it lil tricky.

Comment: Can you post some of the queries you've tried?

Comment: SELECT distinct  a.employee_id , a.oracle_sub_team_code ,a.total_days
FROM resourcetracker_totaldays a
JOIN (SELECT employee_id, COUNT(*)
FROM resourcetracker_totaldays 
GROUP BY employee_id
HAVING count(*) > 1 ) b
ON a.employee_id = b.employee_id
where month_value = 'NOVEMBER'
order by a.employee_id

Comment: I am using this to find the list of records, but i am not able to update one of the rows to 0 where it belongs to two teams

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution works ,

update resourcetracker_totaldays set total_days = 0 where id =
 select id  from 
(SELECT id ,employee_id, total_days, oracle_sub_team_code, ROW_NUMBER() OVER  (PARTITION BY employee_id) AS ranks 
  FROM resourcetracker_totaldays
  where month_value = 'NOVEMBER' ) al
  where ranks > 1

I am finding the rank which gives me 2nd , 3rd occurences of that record in that table , i am taking the records with ranks > 1 and updating all those total_days values to 0 , this will have all records in the table but will have total_days only for one team.